# Entity Framework CodeFirst Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I got ASP.MVC application. I use entity framework with default configuration (no connection string provided) so it creates `.mdf` file in `APP_DATA`.

If I wanna move my project to another pc and try a clean depoly, should I remove this `.mdf` from `APP_DATA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try a `clean deployment`, then YES. If you copy the database file it will be reused and so the migrations are not run (again), as they are already applied.

Comment: Thx. Is there any way to automatically delete all files that not belong to project? Like images that i uploaded in project folder?

Comment: Are you using a Version Control System? Because there you normaly do NOT check in such files => just get a "clean version" from the VCS on the new machine. If you do not use VCS I would recommend to do so (VS will normaly only add the requried files)...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Migrations in your project there should not be any problem.
on new machine you can use command
**"Update-Database"** in your visual studio package manager consol and it will create a new database tables on you new machine.

**NOTE:** it will only create database schema if you need data also to get copied on to new machine you need to use some export utility.